# how to write value in SqlConfiguration.ini file using java api like "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"?

Tags: java, ini

***Current Output:***

[SqlServer2008]

INSTALLSHAREDDIR = C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server

**Required Output:**

INSTALLSHAREDDIR = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

**Java code:**

```
Uesin org.ini4j api..............
String installDoc ="F:\\SQLExpressConfigurationFile_x64.ini";
Wini ini;
File file = new File(installDoc);
    try {
    ini = new Wini(file);
ini.put("SQLSERVER2008", "INSTALLSHAREDDIR", "C:\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server");
ini.store();
```

Please let me know how to get required output with ini4j api or other api. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use backslashes to escape the double quotes like this:

```
"\"C:\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\""
```